# Host the OrangeHRM local instance on godaddy

Tags: localhost, web-hosting, orangehrm

I have installed the OrangeHRM on my local machine; I have customized the application and seeded the data on to the local mysql instance. How can I host the same customized local instance on godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a dump of the database that you used for your local OrangeHRM instance. The dump is a backup from the database that you will need to migrate to your GoDaddy server.
Actually, this procedure is divided in two segments.

First, make a copy from your OrangeHRM files and directories into a tar or zip archive. There are multiple tutorials out there on how to make a tar or zip archive. Then make a dump from the local database. There are also many articles about mysqldump on the Internet, but I will provide you with the one that I always use, because it is effective and there is an rsync example command that I use to do the actual migration from one to another server. Click on this: [mysqldumptutorial](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/backup-and-restore-your-mysql-database/)

The second segment is this:
After you make the needed copies from the files/directories and database, install OrangeHRM on the GoDaddy server. Make the needed virtual host directive, set the document root and after your files/database migration unpack the tar/zip archive into the document root that you configured.
Then, import the database dump with the command from the tutorial above.
If you do this operation correctly, you should be able to open the domain that you configured in the virtual host directive and to be prompted by your local OrangeHRM installation with the imported database.
I hope that this mini guide helps you.